# CSS3 transition events

Tags: javascript, css, events, css-transitions

Are there any events fired by an element to check whether a css3 transition has started or end?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

## [W3C CSS Transitions Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-events-)

> The completion of a CSS Transition generates a corresponding DOM Event. An event is fired for each property that undergoes a transition. This allows a content developer to perform actions that synchronize with the completion of a transition.

---

### [Webkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingCSSTransitions/AnimatingCSSTransitions.html)

> To determine when a transition completes, set a JavaScript event listener function for the DOM event that is sent at the end of a transition. The event is an instance of WebKitTransitionEvent, and its type is `webkitTransitionEnd`.

```
box.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', 
    function( event ) { alert( "Finished transition!" ); }, false );
```

### [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition)

> There is a single event that is fired when transitions complete. In Firefox, the event is `transitionend`, in Opera, `oTransitionEnd`, and in WebKit it is `webkitTransitionEnd`.

### [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto29/css/transitions/#events)

> There is one type of transition event
>   available. The `oTransitionEnd` event
>   occurs at the completion of the
>   transition.

### [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673535(v=vs.85).aspx#transitions_dom_events)

> The `transitionend` event occurs at the completion of the transition. If the transition is removed before completion, the event will not fire.

---

[Stack Overflow: How do I normalize CSS3 Transition functions across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers)

Comment: Note that the event is called "transitionend" in firefox and "oTransitionEnd" in Opera

Comment: No one has mentioned anything about the transition-start part of the question.  Is there no way to register an event handler to be fired before the transition begins?

Comment: Is there now a standard way of achieving this? Seems 2 years is a long time! Things have likely changed.

Comment: @tyler i don't know how to work around the lack of transitions-start.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz linked stackoverflow question has interesting solution.

Comment: looks like IE supports transitionend https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4109

Answer (score 78):

**Update**

All modern browsers now support the unprefixed event:

`element.addEventListener('transitionend', callback, false);`

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

---

I was using the approach given by Pete, however I have now started using the following

```
$(".myClass").one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
function() {
 //do something
});
```

---

Alternatively if you use bootstrap then you can simply do

```
$(".myClass").one($.support.transition.end,
function() {
 //do something
});
```

This is becuase they include the following in bootstrap.js

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: http://www.modernizr.com/)
  // ============================================================

  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
      'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      'transition'       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }

    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }


  $(function () {
    $.support.transition = transitionEnd()
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Note they also include an emulateTransitionEnd function which may be needed to ensure a callback always occurs.

```
  // http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions
  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {
    var called = false, $el = this
    $(this).one($.support.transition.end, function () { called = true })
    var callback = function () { if (!called) $($el).trigger($.support.transition.end) }
    setTimeout(callback, duration)
    return this
  }
```

> Be aware that sometimes this event doesn’t fire, usually in the case
>   when properties don’t change or a paint isn’t triggered. To ensure we
>   always get a callback, let’s set a timeout that’ll trigger the event
>   manually.

http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions

Comment: You can't do something like that. In some cases callbaack will be fired more than once.

Comment: In browsers that keep both the prefixed and the regular event names around. You can workaround it by using .one  instead of .on

Comment: Just fyi: The first solution looks nice and handy but it causes a memory leak:

https://codepen.io/jjd/pen/ZEpGGqG

To avoid that, namespace all of the event names and explicitly deregister them. Otherwise you end up adding a bunch of event listeners, each time the code is executed and those are never cleaned up.

$(".myClass").one('transitionend.namespace webkitTransitionEnd.namespace oTransitionEnd.namespace otransitionend.namespace MSTransitionEnd.namespace', 
function() {
   $(this).off('.namespace');
   //do something
});

Answer (score 61):

All modern browsers [now support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) the unprefixed event:

`element.addEventListener('transitionend', callback, false);`

Works in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Even IE10+.

Answer (score 16):

In Opera 12 when you bind using the plain JavaScript, 'oTransitionEnd' will work:

```
document.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd", function(){
    alert("Transition Ended");
});
```

however if you bind through jQuery, you need to use 'otransitionend'

```
$(document).bind("otransitionend", function(){
    alert("Transition Ended");
});
```

In case you are using Modernizr or bootstrap-transition.js you can simply do a change:

```
var transEndEventNames = {
    'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition'    : 'transitionend',
    'OTransition'      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
    'msTransition'     : 'MSTransitionEnd',
    'transition'       : 'transitionend'
},
transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed('transition') ];
```

You can find some info here as well http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/articles/opera-12-otransitionend-bugs-and-workarounds/

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, don't do this!

```
$.fn.transitiondone = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.trigger('transitiondone');
    }, (parseFloat($this.css('transitionDelay')) + parseFloat($this.css('transitionDuration'))) * 1000);
  });
};


$('div').on('mousedown', function (e) {
  $(this).addClass('bounce').transitiondone();
});

$('div').on('transitiondone', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('bounce');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to detect only a single transition end, without using any JS framework here's a little convenient utility function:

```
function once = function(object,event,callback){
    var handle={};

    var eventNames=event.split(" ");

    var cbWrapper=function(){
        eventNames.forEach(function(e){
            object.removeEventListener(e,cbWrapper, false );
        });
        callback.apply(this,arguments);
    };

    eventNames.forEach(function(e){
        object.addEventListener(e,cbWrapper,false);
    });

    handle.cancel=function(){
        eventNames.forEach(function(e){
            object.removeEventListener(e,cbWrapper, false );
        });
    };

    return handle;
};
```

Usage:

```
var handler = once(document.querySelector('#myElement'), 'transitionend', function(){
   //do something
});
```

then if you wish to cancel at some point you can still do it with

```
handler.cancel();
```

It's good for other event usages as well :)