# webkit transition end in mozilla and opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html, webkit

I wonder if there are some predefined event like the `webkitTransitionEnd` in Chrome in the mozilla and opera browser?

How can I also detect of the browser is webkit enabled and CSS3 ?

Comment: Please note that Opera 12 made some changes in how it names events, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12174628/890492

Comment: This shim can be useful: https://github.com/EvandroLG/transitionEnd

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [the MDN Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) there is such an event:

> There is a single event that is fired when transitions complete. In Firefox, the event is `transitionend`, in Opera, `oTransitionEnd`, and in WebKit it is `webkitTransitionEnd`.

Comment: you mean `transitionEnd`in mozilla?

Comment: @Woho87: that's a direct quote from the documentation, so unless the documentation is wrong, it's `transitionend` as written.

Comment: If you found my answer to be useful, feel free to vote it up (or even accept it) ;-)

Comment: It seems that in Opera, as of version 12, "oTransitionEnd" event was renamed to "otransitionend"; you should register an event handler for both events