# Underscore's throttle function doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is the `_.throttle(function() {}, 250)` function only firing on `click` ? Because I'm trying to run some code with a small delay and it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

```
return _.throttle(function() {
    return ( $(this).hasClass('dataRevealed') ) ? $(this).addClass('animated fadeOut') : true;
}, 350);
```

**EDIT :** The function looks like this :

```
Application.CardView.prototype.removeSimilarCards = function(_container) {
    return $(_container).find('[data-identifier="card-view"]').each(function() {
        console.log("first");
        _.throttle(function() {
            console.log("inner");
            return ( $(this).hasClass('dataRevealed') ) ? $(this).addClass('animated fadeOut') : true;
        }, 350);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why not use window.setTimeout() for the same purpose?

Comment: How do you call that function? Do you expect to get the result of the delayed execution?

Comment: Where is this function being `return`ed from (or to)?

Comment: Just added the entire function, it's called when some condition in my code is met

Comment: `_.throttle` returns a function.  In your `each` you are are calling `_.throttle`, but you are never using the function it returns.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ~ I see, and what other way should I use in order for my delay to occur ?

Comment: Try this: `return $(_container).find(...).each(_.throttle(function(){}, 350));`.

Comment: It works but only for the first one

Comment: Could you please tell us what that `each` snippet is supposed to do? Seems like you misunderstood the purpose of `throttle`.

Comment: `each` loops through all the elements I gather from the container, per say I have 15 divs that are found and then I'm looping all of them and applying the delayed function

Comment: So, you want the function inside the each to be called with a delay? Unfortunately, `_.throttle` is the wrong tool here.  What you want is a function queue.  Add the functions to a queue, then dequeue them using a timeout.

Comment: Wait.  What are you trying to do with the returned value?  You want to delay function calls, but you want to return values?  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: `_.throttle` is used to prevent a function from running too many times by "throttling" it so it only runs once every X ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.throttle` is used to prevent a function from running too many times by "throttling" it so it only runs once every X ms.  You probably want to use a function queue, dequeuing on a delayed timer.

Something like this:

```
Application.CardView.prototype.removeSimilarCards = function(_container) {
    var $ele = $(_container),
        $cards = $ele.find('[data-identifier="card-view"]');

    $cards.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $ele.queue('func', function(next){
            if($this.hasClass('dataRevealed')){
                $this.addClass('animated fadeOut');
            }
            setTimeout(next, 350);
        });
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $ele.dequeue('func');
    }, 350);

    return $cards;
};
```

Comment: Haven't used the '.queue()' until  now :) Though, would there be way to fade them out all at once and now one by one ? The reason why I'm doing this is because there's an animation which takes about 350ms, only after that I will fade out the divs and remove them from the DOM, so maybe should I listen for transitionend ?

Comment: Don't assume that an animation will finish in a certain time.  How are you doing that animation?  It probably has a callback option, use that instead.

Comment: It's CSS animation, a flipping animation

Comment: I've never used CSS animations, but you can try the `transitionend` event.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794186

Answer (score 6):

As in the official document [underscore#throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) mentioned, the passed in function has to be a **throttled version**. You see, the "throttling" has to be executed before it is passed in. I just got this working. :) @closure mentioned this in above comment. We should read the official document more.

```
var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some other issue in your code.

I have created a sample to show that it is working perfectly [see example](http://jsbin.com/asaxod/4/watch)

Here is the code:

```
var refTime = +new Date();
var fn = _.throttle(function() {
    console.log((+new Date() - refTime)/1000);
}, 3000);

window.setInterval(fn, 10);
```

Comment: I have no idea what could be going wrong, because I'm also using the `_.debounce` somewhere else and it works just fine

Comment: Had a doubt about $(this) not working, but that is working too. Check: http://jsbin.com/asaxod/8/watch

Comment: May be swap code in your throttle to something else to debug.

Comment: I just found that it's because my each function I think @raghaw :)

Comment: I found the issue in your code. You are not receiving _throttle response anywhere. That is the function you must refer.

Comment: function handle passed to each should be throttle function

Comment: You mean something like : ` $(_container).find(...).each(_.throttle(function(){}, 350));` , but that only makes the first encounter work, the rest are not delayed