# Can I hide/show this menu with CSS3 and or javascript without a timeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/blankasaurus/YPR4U/15/embedded/result/

I have the layout functioning how I want it to function. I'm not sure I like having to set the width in the toggle function:

```
 $('.content').css('width', '100%');

 $('.content').css('width', '75%');
```

and I also REALLY don't like having to set a timeout before showing and hiding the menu panel:

```
 setTimeout(function()
 {
     $('.sidebar').fadeIn();
 }, 1001);
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Here's a fiddle:

Answer (score 0):

For the fading out, you can just use a callback function passed into `fadeOut`.

For example:

```
$('.sidebar').fadeOut( 400, function() {
    $('.content').css('width', '100%');
});
```

For the fading in, you could try using [transition events](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-events-). You'll just have to write specific code for different browsers, and not surprisingly, older browsers are not supported.
More details can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794186/911140)