# Change function “document.getElementById” to “document.getElementsByClassName” & add fade in/out - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

my knowledge of JavaScript is incredibly limited and I hope someone would be able to help me out!

I have the code below, I'm trying to make the code work with class rather then id and also add a fade in/out effect on these functions. I've added a class and id set to try make it as clear as possible what I'm trying to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>  
        .sub1, .sub2 {
        float: right;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        display: none;
        }

        #sub1, #sub2 {
        float: right;
        background-color: red;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // class
        function SetTabsHidden(tabToHide)
        {
         document.getElementsByClassName('.sub1').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementsByClassName('.sub2').style.display = "none";

        }


        function SetTabsVisible(tabToShow)
        {
         document.getElementsByClassName('.sub1').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementsByClassName('.sub2').style.display = "none";

         document.getElementsByClassName(tabToShow).style.display = "block";

        }

    // id
        function SetTabsHidden(tabToHide)
        {
         document.getElementById('sub1').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById('sub2').style.display = "none";                         
         $(tabToHide).fadeOut("slow");
        }


        function SetTabsVisible(tabToShow)
        {
         elements = document.getElementById('sub1').style.display = "none";
         elements = document.getElementById('sub2').style.display = "none";

         elements = document.getElementById(tabToShow).style.display = "block";
         $(tabToShow).fadeIn("slow");

        }   


    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="main">
    <input type=button name=type value='class1' onclick="SetTabsVisible('.sub1');";>
    <input type=button name=type value='class2' onclick="SetTabsVisible('.sub2');";>
    <input type=button name=type value='id1' onclick="SetTabsVisible('sub1');";>
    <input type=button name=type value='id2' onclick="SetTabsVisible('sub2');";>

    <input type=button name=type value='Hide' onclick="SetTabsHidden();";>


    <div class="sub1" id="sub1"></div>

    <div class="sub2" id="sub2"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getElementsByClassName` won't work because you don't want to include the period before the class name (you'll notice that byID doesn't include the #. Same idea) Just change it to sub1 or sub2 or whatever and it should start working.

You have four functions defined but they have the same names, which isn't going to work.

You'll have to name them something different like "SetTabsVisibleByClass" ....OR you can only use two functions but pass in another parameter letting it know whether it's a class or an id that you want it to use.

---

Your example code uses jQuery for the fading. If you're planning on using jQuery you don't need all that extra logic. It can handle it for you:

`$(".sub1, .sub2").hide()`

or, if they're all contained together you could do:

`$(tabToShow).siblings().hide()`

and then you don't have to remember all the different class names.

---

If you're not planning on using jQuery then for the fading you could also use CSS transitions. Something like:

```
.sub1, .sub2, .sub3 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.sub1.active, .sub2.active, .sub3.active {
  opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

annnd

`document.getElementById(tabToShow).setAttribute("class", "active")`

Of course, this method means not using `display: none`, which might be important to  you.  In that case you may want to add [event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events) for `transitionEnd` to know when to add display: none.