# CSS3 transition get target param value before animation end

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Is it possible to get some param target value (for example height) of css3 transition element before animation ends.

For example we have `div` with css

```
div {height: 300px;}
```

This div has height transition css

Then we create class

```
div.big {height: 450px;}
```

And then we run jQuery code:

```
var height = $('div').addClass('big').height();
```

How to make `height` variable to be 450, not 300 or 301px as it just beginned changing its height?

I would avoid removing its transition css as it would cause flickr.

Comment: are you wanting to know when the transition has ended? there is transitionend event (with browser prefixes) but seems unpredictable in my experience. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var height = $('div').addClass('big')[0].style.height;
```