# JavaScript display none after CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, css

I have div with id='mainmenu'. I'm adding CSS3 transition to it by JavaScript after button click (by adding 'transition' to #mainmenu and by creating class .fadein and .fadeout that will be added to the div element). Code:

```
<div id='mainmenu'></div>
<button id="btn1">Click me1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click me2</button>

#mainmenu {
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    background:#eee; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s; 
    transition: opacity 1s; 
}

.fadeout {
    opacity:0;
}
.fadein {
    opacity:1;
}


var menu = document.getElementById('mainmenu'),
    btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1'),
    btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadeout';
}
btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadein';
}
```

The problem is that now I want to add display none and block to fadeout and fadein option. So after the fadeout animation div should get display none, and after fadein display block:

```
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadeout';
    menu.style.display = 'none';
}
btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadein';
    menu.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Unfortunately, the display none and block executes with the animation, so the animation isn't working (element gets display none, without the opacity animation). I want first the animation with opacity, and after that display none/block for the element. Is there any way to do it? I can use only pure JavaScript (no jQuery etc.).

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle.js with the code.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout()` with `menu.style.display = "none";` in order to let fade do it's job before you trigger `style.display`.

```
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadeout';
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(menu).css('display', 'none');
    }, 1000);
}
btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.className = 'fadein';
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(menu).css('display', 'block');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: There is a small problem - when you have 'menu' in setTimeout(function(menu){}), the console shows 'Cannot read property 'style' of undefined'. Removing 'menu' from function will fix that problem. Thank you for help.

Comment: of course, hesitated about whether to include that for a sec the first time and made a mistake

Comment: Curious about which browser supports .hide()/.show() - In chrome you would get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'hide'`

Comment: dc5 - in your case, it's probably a problem of jQuery library not being included, or a conflict with another library. If you use other libraries, try using "jQuery" instead of "$". Another possibility is that you are passing the wrong object. There is an example here : http://api.jquery.com/hide/ , which works on my chrome.

Comment: @JevgeniBogatyrjov: The problem was the answer code using the same variable name ('menu') for both the DOM Node ('menu.className') and jQuery ('menu.hide'). Fixed :)

Answer (score 13):

Although this is an old post, for future visitor's sake, you can use the transitionend event. You can use:

```js
/*For when object has fully faded*/
menu.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
  if (this.className == "fadeout") {
    this.style.display = "none";
  }
}.bind(menu));

/*Show before animation starts*/
menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.display = "block";
}.bind(menu));
```

Answer (score 10):

I could be wrong here, however i believe you need to add a transition-end trigger that does the display:block / display:none change.

see: [CSS3 transition events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events)

Comment: You cannot have CSS transition event "display"

Answer (score 8):

I use height 0 instead of display none for some cases but It may or may not apply for what you need. Anyway here's the code:

1) Using transitions (looks like jQuerys fadeOut):

```
.fadeOut{
  opacity : 0;
  height : 0;
  transition : opacity 800ms, height 0 800ms;
}
```

if you want you can add width 0 too.

```
.fadeOut{
  opacity : 0;
  width : 0;
  height : 0;
  transition : opacity 800ms, height 0 800ms, width 0 800ms;
}
```

2) Using animations (it works but transitions is better):

```
.fadeOut{
  animation : fadeout 800ms linear forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeout{
  99%{
    opacity : 0;
    height : initial;
  }
  100%{
    opacity : 0;
    height : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oooh! That's super smart to use `height: 0` so you can keep the logic with the CSS where it belongs. I'm usin' this!

Comment: Note that this could be an accessibility issue. The content would still be available to assistive technology when using `height: 0` instead of `display: none`

Comment: I think that's true. Consider reading https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility