# `display: none` not working in css animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I wrote a little code to have cards fade out and then be set to `display: none;` once clicked so it's not shown in the DOM after it has faded out. Although `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` works, but only the change on the `display`element seems to have no effect; if you hover over the area the cursor is still there, and the element is still shown in dev tools. Is there a way to make sure that the `display: none;`property is set properly?

[CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/Pr3casatDragon/pen/zPaNor)

HTML `<div></div>`

CSS

```
body {
 background: black;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  animation: hiddenTransition 300ms ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; // DOESN'T WORK :C
  will-change: opacity, transform, display;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes hiddenTransition {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
    display: block;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20%);
    display: block;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20%);
    display: none;
  }  
}
```

JS

```
  var square = document.querySelector("div");

  square.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
```

Comment: I think you will need to trigger the display none separately after the animation has completed. Take a look at the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601648/javascript-display-none-after-css3-animation) to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only way to achieve this is with JS, which is what [vitilok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6181985/vitiok) posted in this comment:

> Well, this is a bit tricky. So in order to accomplish what you want do the following: 1. remove display from will-change as well as from all frames. 2. add a new class .visuallyhidden { display: none; } 3. add: " setTimeout(function() { square.classList.add("visuallyhidden") }, 500) " inside the callback of click. You can see working example [here](https://codepen.io/vitiok/pen/OOEovJ) And read [this link](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/) if you want explanation

Basically, he put a `setTimeout` statement which changed the `display` property to `none` after the animation time.

Their CSS

```
.visuallyhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Their JS

```
setTimeout(function() {
  square.classList.add("visuallyhidden")
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

working code pen [here](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/qVKyQX)

Note:-display property can't be animated

```
body {
  background: black;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

div {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  animation: hiddenTransition 300ms ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; // DOESN'T WORK :C
  will-change: opacity, transform, display;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@keyframes hiddenTransition {
  0% {

    transform: none;
    visibility:visible;
  }
  99% {

    transform: translateY(20%);

    visibility:visible;
  }

  100% {

    transform: translateY(20%);
    visibility:hidden;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve anything for me because it still takes up space in the window

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set `display: none`, the element still will be present in devtools. Regarding the cursor, just change cursor display to default in the hidden class. Like so: `cursor: default;`

Comment: It's present as in it still shows up in the browser window and is still clickable.  If I change the opacity in the animation to something that's not 0, it's still clearly visible, so therefore it's clear that the `display: none` is simply not being applied.

Comment: display: none - has no effect on layout.(according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)). That means it will NOT prevent the browser from parsing/loading that markup, but it will prevent from applying styles to it.

Comment: Do you need it to toggle back on click?

Comment: Nope, but in the project I'm working on, it will be fading back in when something else is clicked

Comment: Well, this is a bit tricky. So in order to accomplish what you want do the following:
1. remove display from will-change as well as from all frames.
2. add a new class .visuallyhidden { display: none; }
3. add: " setTimeout(function() {
      square.classList.add("visuallyhidden")
    }, 500) " inside the callback of click

Comment: You can see working example [here](https://codepen.io/vitiok/pen/OOEovJ) And read [this](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/) link if you want explanation

Answer (score 0):

As others said the `display` css property not work in css animation, so I have to set the property by js code.

```js
img.classList.add('content-img') // css animation class name
img.onanimationend = () => {
  img.style.display='none' // hide the element after animation
};
```