# Jquery - Using promise API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to create a simple progress bar. I need to get an event / perform action when the animation on the progress bar complete (100% width is filled by green color).

HTML -

```
<button>Go</button>
<p>Waiting</p>
<div id="bar" class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-bar-fill"></div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #EEE;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.progress-bar-fill {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    transition: width 5s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}
```

JS -

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("p").append(" --> Started");
    $('#bar .progress-bar-fill').css('width', '100%');
    $('#bar .progress-bar-fill').promise().done(function () {
        $("p").append(" --> Finished");
    });
});
```

Link - http://jsfiddle.net/v2unc/

WRT the code, the "Finished" indication should come after 5 seconds. But its coming as soon as the button is clicked.

The example in "http://api.jquery.com/promise/" works perfectly. Or am I looking at the wrong API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ontransitionend` event for CSS3 animation:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v2unc/1/)

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("p").append(" --> Started");
    $('#bar .progress-bar-fill').css('width', '100%').on('transitionend', function () {
        $("p").append(" --> Finished");
    });
});
```

Comment: What an awesome solution.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the wrong API. `.promise` returns a promise that gets fulfilled when a [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) of pending operations on an element has been completed. By default this means the animation queue. Your progress bar is not being animated *by jQuery*, so the animation queue is empty at all times and the promise resolves immediately.

Since the progress bar is being animated by a CSS transition, the simplest thing you can do is set a timer synchronized with the transition duration, e.g.

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $("p").append(" --> Started");
    $('#bar .progress-bar-fill').css('width', '100%');
    setTimeout(5000, function () {
        $("p").append(" --> Finished");
    });
});
```

Of course this is rather low tech and requires you to repeat the transition duration (bad). Instead of this, prefer the [`transitionEnd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events) event.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Sorry, but I need to accept the answer form 'A. Wolff'. Its 2 minutes earlier.

Comment: @NEB: No worries. But where did you get the 2 mins earlier from?

Comment: As of now, what I can see is you answer is "27 minutes old" and Wolff's is "25 minutes old", shown just above the image of the one who has answered the question.

Comment: @NEB: ...which means mine was 2 minutes earlier :-) Just FYI, I don't really need the accept. Cheers!