# How do I add a pause in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this:

```
<div style="width: 0%;"></div>
```

How can I change the css of `width` to `100%` (and wait until it reaches 100%) before changing more elements?

For example:

```
$('div').css('width', '100%', function() {
    $('div').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but how can I make it work?

Comment: What do you mean wait until the width is 100%? Do you have some CSS transitions enabled? Otherwise this change is instant and there's no 'waiting' period.

Comment: Do you want to animate the css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 transition events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events)

Comment: How long does resizing take? Do you set that value?

Comment: @oGeez How would I make it set width to 100%, and wait 2 seconds?

Comment: you need to use Jquery's animate function and take advantage of the callback

Comment: @user3390776 You should really say that in your question it's not clear what you're looking for. Answer added none-the-less.

Comment: Define 'wait'. Are you wanting to animate the change to 100% width? Or is it just an instantaneous thing? If the latter, there is no need to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a timer to wait before processing some more code:

```
$('div').css('width', '100%');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('div').css('color','red');
}, 2000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hUmg/)

Comment: I was going to say this doesn't handle the animation, but now that I re-read the question, I'm not sure animation is a part of the question. Hrm...

Comment: There's no mention of animation in the question, which is why I was a little confused by the other answers, I guess they are based on assumptions? This is based on the comment that the OP left.

Comment: Yea, I totally assumed an animation but that serves me right for not re-reading the question! :)

Comment: There's no waiting for anything to finish here... Should the question be, "How can I do something and then do something x seconds later?"

Comment: @JuanMendes Probably, yeah.

Comment: @JuanMendes yes, it should! I tried to come up with a better title with the edit.

Comment: It happens all-too-often here. Not only do we work out the answers but also work out the question that the OP is trying to ask. It's part of what we (as answerers) do.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery animate()

```
$("div").animate({
    width:"100%" 
  }, 2000, function() {
    //On Animation complete
    $('div').css('color', 'red');
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/gvr5R/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a number of ways. One way is to use CSS transitions:

```
.yourDiv {
    width: 0%;
    -webkit-transition: width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
    background: yellow;
}

.yourDiv.wide {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, to animate, apply the class via jQuery:

```
$('.yourDiv').addClass('wide')
```

To do something after it's done animating, use the webkitTransitionEnd event:

```
$('.yourDiv')
    .addClass('wide')
    .one('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
        $('this').css('background','red')
    })
```

If you wan to wait for a period of time after the animation finished before triggering your next style change, wrap it in a setTimeout:

var $yourDiv = $('.yourDiv')

```
$yourDiv
    .addClass('wide')
    .one('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $yourDiv.css('background','red')
            },2000)
    })
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22fPQ/1/

(note the above is webkit-centric. Use other browser CSS prefixes as needed to support)