# jQuery should wait until css transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a simple slideshow in a div, see my fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5m9Lgj7o/
It's working fine so far.

But I have a css transition for the table:

```
.gallery-table {
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
```

The problem is, that when the transition has not finished yet, the calculation of "actLeft" is wrong when clicking to quick on the left or right controls.

How can I tell my functions leftControl.click() and rightControl.click() to wait until transition has ended? Or is this the wrong way?

I tried one() and queue() and delay(), but I don't get the solution...

Comment: use javascript setTimeout(function(){},500)

Comment: You can try bxslider which has many more options to control your transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CC3 generates DOM events, so you can sing on TransitionEnd event.
See more info on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events) answer.

Comment: In addition: To stop events from stacking up, you could use `$().once()`. Or, you could just add an event handler earlier than the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

SetTimeout function will do the work.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m9Lgj7o/3/).

```
setTimeout(
            function() {
                alert("Called after delay.");
            },
            2000);
```

This piece of code is added to each of the click functions

Answer (score 1):

I think, the most "straight" solution for your task is to use $.animate()
http://api.jquery.com/animate/