# jQuery looping doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a bird wing (to flap a little bit up and down) using the below code:

```js
$bird_wing_left = $(".bird_wing_left");

function rotate($bodysec) {

  $bodysec.animate({ 
    transform: "rotate(30deg)"
  }, 0, function() {
    $(this).css({
      transform: "rotate(70deg)"
    });
    rotate($(this)) ;
  });

}

rotate ($bird_wing_left) ;
```

```css
.bird_wing_left {
  margin: 50px ;
  width: 100px ;
  height: 100px ;
  background: blue ;
}
```

```html
<div class="bird_wing_left"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, the code doesn't loop. It would just rotate to 70 degrees and stop there. I called the function inside the function so I'm not sure why it's not looping.

Comment: because using an animate with a duration of 0 seems pretty useless. also, we dont see your css transitions. have a look at css transition end events in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events

Answer (score 0):

Your `transform` call does nothing because you specify an animation time of `0`. If you want an immediate transformation, use `css` as in your callback. Moreover, looking at the development console in Chrome showed a `too much recursion` error, so what you should do is rewrite your code using `setInterval`:

```
$bird_wing_left = $(".bird_wing_left");

function rotate ($bodysec) {
  (function () {
    var $_bodysec = $bodysec ;
    var $_angle   = 30 ;
    setInterval (function () {
      $_bodysec.css({
        transform: "rotate(" + $_angle + "deg)"
      });
      $_angle = $_angle == 70 ? 30 : 70 ;
    }, 200) ;

  }) () ;
}

rotate ($bird_wing_left) ;
```

```js
$bird_wing_left = $(".bird_wing_left");

function rotate ($bodysec) {
  (function () {
    var $_bodysec = $bodysec ;
    var $_angle   = 30 ;
    setInterval (function () {
      $_bodysec.css({
        transform: "rotate(" + $_angle + "deg)"
      });
      $_angle = $_angle == 70 ? 30 : 70 ;
    }, 200) ;
    
  }) () ;
}

rotate ($bird_wing_left) ;
```

```css
.bird_wing_left {
  margin: 50px ;
  width: 100px ;
  height: 100px ;
  background: blue ;
}
```

```html
<div class="bird_wing_left"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```