# I simply want the second function to run after the first and so on. the first function is being called in the html page by body onload="runOne()"

Tags: javascript

```
function runOne() {
    rightBox.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s 1";
}

function runTwo() {
    rightBoxTwo.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s 1";
}

function runThree() {
    rightBoxThree.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s 1";
}
```

This question has been asked before but answered with jquery, please simply looking for an example with non jquery syntax, if it not possible to have these run in order only after the previous one completes using javascript please explain why? i understand the concept of synchronous and asynchronous code so a definition of these terms is not needed as well. just a working example, enough code has been provided.

calling the second funtction from the first like so:

```
function runOne() {rightBox.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s 1"; runTwo();}
```

does not attain the goal of running one only after the first is complete

Comment: If you want it the animation timings to be 100% accurate i guess it'd be best to catch the animation end event, maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2794186/4341456) or [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback) can help.

Answer (score 0):

So use setTimeout

```
function runOne() {
    rightBox.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s 1";
    setTimeout(runTwo,10000);
}
```

You can also try to use the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event

```
rightBox.addEventListener("transitionend",runTwo, false);
```

Comment: is there a way to run the second function only after the first completes irregardles of how much time is involved in the first one or second one?

Comment: or does javascript not detect the completion of functions?

Comment: @German you extract the time from the animation property, multiply it by 1000 and pass to the setTimeout. Or just make a variable with the animation time, and pass it to the animation property and then setTimeout.

Comment: tried this butto didnt work - function runOne(){
 rightBox.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s";
 }

    function runTwo(){
 rightBoxTwo.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s";
 }

    function runThree(){
 rightBoxTwo.style.animation = "scrollTextTwo 10s";
 }


    rightBox.addEventListener("animationend",runTwo,false);