# Is there any way to know if element's CSS animation finished or is still going?

Tags: css-transitions

If I start transition on element by adding a class, can I somehow figure out if it finished or do I need to measure time separately?

Or even better, can I get current intermediate values?

Comment: There are events you can subscribe to, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 transition events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2794148/11683)

Comment: Note that animation and transitions are different things, which need different handling in JS. (Just saying, because your title has "animation" while the post has "transition".)