# Is there a callback after an element's css style has completed transition?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem when handling CSS transitions:

```
elem.style.height = new_height;
await waitUntilCSSUpdated(elem);
await waitUntilCurrentTransitionEnd(elem);
<...some codes>
```

Note: This code is loaded with the `async` attribute.

The second function `waitUntilCurrentTransitionEnd` works correctly, but I am having trouble with `waitUntilCSSUpdated` to get the exact CSS update time. It seems to differ for each browser. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can attach the transitionend event which is fired when the css transition has completed

Comment: You could possibly use `requestAnimationFrame()` and in that callback, check the `height` to see if it is whatever the new `height` is supposed to be.

Comment: I have tried "requestAnimationFrame" this method. If I only wait until next frame, in Firefox PC it always works. However, in Chrome and Android Firefox it doesn't work. And also, if I check style and surround it with a loop, how can I do the same thing with "elem.classList.add"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 transition events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794148/css3-transition-events)