# jQuery addEventListener not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.uiModalWrapper').live('click', function() {

                            var modal = $(this).find('.uiModal');

                            modal.addClass('shake');

                            modal.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {

                                modal.removeClass('shake');

                            });


                        });
```

Which should add a class called shake to an element when it's clicked and then remove it again when the webkitAnimationEnd event takes place. However it causes an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'`

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: You should read more about jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 1):

`modal` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. It doesn't have `addEventLister`, it has the jQuery stuff for adding listeners (`on`?).

Answer (score 0):

you could get the modal element just with `var modal = $('.uiModal');` and then you can work with the DOM element

Comment: That would get _all_ ".uiModal" elements, not just the ones inside the clicked ".uiModalWrapper" element, and it would still be a jQuery object - need to say `modal[0]` to work with the (first) DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem: [Is there a callback on completion of a CSS3 animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)

Seems using BIND will do the trick.