# How to add a fade out at the end of this CSS animation?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Animation: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wJAip

[image]

If you click the **Animate Down** button the jQuery will add the `.animateDown` class to the spinner. The spinner will then animate down to 0, but then pop back up to fullsize again.

How would you add a new keyframe at the end in CSS to hide the spinner after it shrinks?

*Or*

In jQuery would would I listen for when the spinner is scaled down to 0 then hide() it?

*CSS:*

```
.animateDown {
    -webkit-animation: animateDown .3s ease-in-out;
    animation: animateDown .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateDown { 
    0%  {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% { 
       -webkit-transform: scale(0);
       transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

*jQuery:*

```
$('#animate-down').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
    $('#spinner').removeClass('animateUp');
    $('#spinner').addClass('animateDown');
});
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation

Comment: SWEET That worked! :D thanks, uhm do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sypjf

You can use 'forwards' so that the CSS animation does not repeat:

```
.animateUp {
  -webkit-animation: animateUp .6s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: animateUp .6s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.animateDown {
  -webkit-animation: animateDown .3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: animateDown .3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

And add opacity: 0 to the keyframe so that the element becomes invisible (not quite the same as $.hide():

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateDown { 
0%  {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);

  }
100% { 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Also don't forget to add the -moz prefixes, your demo currently doesn’t work in Firefox.

Comment: NICE! I like this even better :) Yeah I was wondering what was going on in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Also for a pure CSS solution take a look at [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

In your case: `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Only problem may be the cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the problem right, you need to attach a callback to the css animation.  Something like this.

```
$(".animateDown").bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
   alert("fin") 
});
```

As seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)

Edit: there is a pure JS version too, but I like my jQuery :).