# Running code after an AngularJS animation has completed

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I have an element whose visibility is toggled by `ng-show`. I'm also using CSS animations - the automatic ones from ng-animate - on this element to animate its entry.

The element will either contain an image or a video.

In the case that the element contains a video, I want to play it, but I don't want to play the video until it's finished animating in.

As such, I was wondering if there's an easy way to bind a callback to the end of a **CSS** animation in AngularJS?

The [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.%24animate) reference a `doneCallback`, but I can't see a way to specify it...

One workaround(?) I have thought of is `$watch`ing `element.hasClass("ng-hide-add-active")` and waiting for it to fire with `(true, false)`, implying it's just been removed..

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: you specify amount of seconds in css animations, set same amount in $timeout?

Comment: @YOU : I could do but that's even less neat in my opinion - the two are completely decoupled from eachother.

Comment: btw, there is some question regarding css animation callbacks - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6186454 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/9255279 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087510

Comment: Thanks but this question is more about angularjs than generic css animations.

Comment: What you see in the docs is meant for directives. And I strongly recommend to implement one, as it's the only clean solution IMHO.

Comment: @zeroflagL I see - the element I'm animating in & out is a directive already? Is that what you mean? Or should I implement some kind of custom animation directive?

Comment: Instead of ng-show you use your own directive. Or if you already have one then use it for your animation as well and remove ng-show.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into doing this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@michael-charemza answer worked great for me.  If you are using Angular 1.3 they changed the promise a little.  I got stuck on this for a little bit but here is the change that got it to work:

```
if (show) {
  $animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide').then(scope.afterShow);
}
if (!show) {
  $animate.addClass(element, 'ng-hide').then(scope.afterHide);
}
```

Plunker: [Code Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/C8OjSs0rplrghLn1KRmd?p=preview)

Answer (score 26):

As @zeroflagL has suggested, a custom directive to replace `ngShow` is probably the way to go. You can use `&` to pass callbacks into the directive, which can be called after the animations have finished. For consistency, the animations are done by adding and removing the `ng-hide` class, which is the same method used by the usual ngShow directive:

```
app.directive('myShow', function($animate) {
  return {
    scope: {
      'myShow': '=',
      'afterShow': '&',
      'afterHide': '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('myShow', function(show, oldShow) {
        if (show) {
          $animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide', scope.afterShow);
        }
        if (!show) {
          $animate.addClass(element, 'ng-hide', scope.afterHide);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Example use of this listening to a scope variable `show` would be:

```
<div my-show="show" after-hide="afterHide()" after-show="afterShow()">...</div>
```

Because this is adding/removing the ng-hide class, the points about animating [from the docs about ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow) are still valid, and you need to add `display: block !important` to the CSS.

You can [see an example of this in action at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n2nKeoBAKXTH2RdNcV2G?p=preview).

Comment: I around with this on Plunker and works great - however if I change the angular to version 1.3 then the callback is no longer fired. It looks like the addClass and removeClass functions no longer take a callback?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like you have to use .then(function() {}); for version 1.3

Comment: Also, if you're going to be using css animations, be sure to add `{tempClasses: 'ng-hide-animate'}` as the third argument after `element` and `'ng-hide'` before calling `.then` as mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

@michal-charemza solution works great, but the directive creates an isolated scope, so in some cases it cannot be a direct replacement for the default ng-show directive.

I have modified it a bit, so that it does not create any new scopes and can be used interchangeably with the ng-show directive.

```js
app.directive('myShow', function($animate) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs['myShow'], function(show, oldShow) {
        if (show) {
          $animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide').then(function(){
            scope.$apply(attrs['myAfterShow']);
          });
        } else {
          $animate.addClass(element, 'ng-hide').then(function(){
            scope.$apply(attrs['myAfterHide']);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<div my-show="show" my-after-hide="afterHide()" my-after-show="afterShow()">...</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fjtWnaLNWgWphaklzzwO?p=preview)