# Angular ng-show event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

**Context :**
I use `ng-show` (or `ng-hide`) to show a chart (`hightchart-ng`) only when my data is loaded.

The chart redraws when the data is loaded. So in theory, it redraws at the same time I show the chart. But the chart redraws when it is still not displayed (display: none), so it applies default size (not the real size available when shown).

**Question :** 
Let's say i have an expression `A` used in my template with `ng-show` :

```
    <div ng-show="A">
        <highchart config="myconfig"></highchart>
    </div>
```

I can't watch `A` to redraw manually my chart, cause it would be the same problem.

I don't want to know when `A` is true, but when`A` is true **AND** `ng-show` ended to show the chart.

Any idea ?

**Edit Solution :** I found a solution. Creating a directives which look at the class of the element, like it is explained here :
[Running code after an AngularJS animation has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921622/running-code-after-an-angularjs-animation-has-completed)

Comment: use the A as a scope variable and assign it the value in controller. i.e
$scope.A= false // when wanna hide and 
$scope.A = true // wanna show the chart

Comment: I don't get your idea, it is already a variable in the scope. My problem is that i don't want to know when `A` is true, but when `A` is true **AND** `ng-show` ended to show the chart.