# Angular ng-show slowly hidden

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" ng-show="vm.isSearchIconVisible" after-hide="afterHide()" after-show="afterShow()">
       <i class="iconMglass"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="reset" my-show="!vm.isSearchIconVisible" after-hide="afterHide()" after-show="afterShow()" class="clearTextButton" ng-click="vm.clearSearchText()" >
       <span class="clearIcon">X</span>
   </button>
```

Hi,

I have two buttons that sits one on top of the other and I want to switch between them visually with a flag (isSearchIconVisible).
Logicly it works fine, but there is 500ms that they are seen together and overlapping.
I've used [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921622/running-code-after-an-angularjs-animation-has-completed) to catch the ng-show completed "event".

Comment: what is "my-show" in second button?

Comment: Can you provide code with fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding those styles in your stylesheets.

```
.ng-hide.ng-hide-animate {
     display: none !important;
 }

.ng-animate.no-animate {
     transition: 0s none;
     -webkit-transition: 0s none;
     animation: 0s none;
     -webkit-animation: 0s none;
 }
```