# Add a class then do something after class has been added

Tags: jquery, css

Hey guys i am working on a slider where i have to add a class with transform property and once the class is added fully and the animation is complete add or remove another class.
Now this is code i did but it didn't work.

```
    $('.backgroundImage').addClass('anim', function(){
 $('.backgroundImage').removeClass('anotherClass');
```

Here i am trying to add a class to `.backgroundImage` called `anim` and once is fully attached remove the second class `.anotherClass`
the idea is to do this when one class is fully attached then only other gets removed and not simultaneously.
Please tell me where i am doing wrong.
thanks.

Comment: Can i use a dely on AddClass or RemoveClass?

Comment: @designerNProgrammer I think `.delay()` will only work on queued jQuery things, add / remove wont be effected. A 'setTimeout()' would be needed. Add / remove class do not have a callback function for when they're complete, nor do they have a speed that delay will effect.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy so tell me how can i fix that? please throw me an answer.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer, http://jsfiddle.net/F4NN8/1/ something like this... Yes, you are right, delay() will not work,my fault. :) p.s. you just have to set duration (in ms) of css animation...

Comment: you don't need a time out, animate already has a call back when it is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understand your issue correctly this may help:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7W2p/)**

So what I get is that you're using a CSS animation and want to do stuff after it's done. As far as I know the add / remove class is immediate, and there isn't an easy way to tell once a CSS animation tied to a class is complete. So you'll just have to hand code the animation time in the JS (unless someone knows a better way).

You add the first class, and then call `setTimeout()` on with a delay equal to your first class's animation duration. Then in the timeout you remove the old class, and add the new one. In this example I set the delay to 1 second, but it could be anything.

JS:

```
var animationDuration = 1000; // 1 second

$('.test').addClass('yourFirstClass');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.test').removeClass('yourFirstClass').addClass('yourSecondClass');
}, animationDuration);
```

Comment: @badGuy thanks. if you feel like it's a genuine question , please upvote.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add/remove the next class on the transform property not on the "addClass" function.

see samples in the jquery docs.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

if you are using CSS3 to animate then you may want to read this post:

[Is there a callback on completion of a CSS3 animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)

Comment: Hey Buddy can you make me a quick fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

The [original doc (see it here)](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) doesn't say anything about multiple parameters. Just one string per **addClass** call. The examples are:

```
$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );

$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass noClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```

As of jQuery 1.4, the .addClass() method's argument can receive a function.

```
$( "ul li" ).addClass(function( index ) {
    return "item-" + index;
});
```

So I recommend you to use the following in your code:

```
$('.backgroundImage').addClass('anim');
$('.backgroundImage').removeClass('anotherClass');
```

It seems to be just what you are doing (except for the function I removed).