# Remove background color slowly and only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's need to be like by new messages- by hover (see css below) it's background will slowly disappear, but it can be only once, that is why i need to remove this additional class e.g. "newmessage" which gives this background, but if i remove this class by hover- i haven't this slow effect...

```
.newmessage {
  background-color: rgba(213, 213, 213, 1);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
.newmessage:hover {
  background-color: rgba(213, 213, 213, 0);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML element you are applying this class to?

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jaes2g9g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class that applies the style rule when the element is hovered using JavaScript.  It will only add it once, causing the element's style to transition.  [Updated version of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaes2g9g/1/)

**DEMO**

```js
var newMessages = document.querySelectorAll('.newmessage');


for (var i = 0, l = newMessages.length; i < l; i++) {
    //added the .hovered class on mouseover
    newMessages[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        this.classList.add('hovered');
    });
}
```

```css
div {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.newmessage {
  background-color: rgba(220, 55, 55, 1);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
/* instead of .newmessage:hover, use additional class */
.newmessage.hovered {
  background-color: rgba(220, 55, 55, 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="newmessage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to execute a callback once the trasition is over to remove the class.

[Is there a callback on completion of a CSS3 animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)

> Yes, there is. The callback is an event, so you must add an event
>   listener to catch it. This is an example with jQuery:
>
> ```
> $("#sun").bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
>    alert("fin") 
> });
> ```
>
> Or pure js:
>
> ```
> element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callfunction,false);
> element.addEventListener("animationend", callfunction,false);
> element.addEventListener("oanimationend", callfunction,false);
> ```
>
> Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W3y7h/

Credits to @Duopixel

In your case, you might have to go with `transitionend` instead of `animationend`.