# SetTimeout on vanilla JS on []forEach.call not working in sequences

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate all LI in a sequence, but the code is animating all LI at once.

I could not find a useful reply anywhere, I know how to do this in Jquery, but something does not add up here.

I have tried to add the Timeout to the eventhandler and the called function, both approaches do not work.

This is the function

```
function changeLi() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    [].forEach.call(li, function(li) {
      li.style.transform = "translateX(200px)";
    }, 900);
  });
}
```

Link to codepen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PzYXmv

I have tried to add stopPropagation/preventDefault to the call, but that did not help either.

Comment: Your brace matching is messed up. Please fix it and properly indent your code.

Comment: You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding of [how setTimeout works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). Also [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) and [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), both of which apply only to events.

Comment: You're using `setTimeout` as if it worked like a `sleep`. See [here](Python while loop conversion to Javascript) for solutions.

Comment: `setTimeout()` will only control when an animation starts, when setting the `style.transform`. The animation itself will behave and complete independently of the timeouts. – [Is there a callback on completion of a CSS3 animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)

Comment: @hamms
I have tried the stopPropagation because the whole UL is animated.
The next issue is with the "this" scope, Jquery takes care of that, but here, clearly something is not right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First, the `900` is not a parameter of your `setTimeout`, but rather of the `forEach.call`. That appears to be just an error.

Secondly, even if the above is fixed, your code would simple set a single timeout for 900ms in the future to then iterate over all of your `li`'s in the list and transform them *at once*. What I believe you really want to do is loop over all your items and define a timeout to run in the future where each is run a certain amount of time from the previous. Since `forEach` provides an index, you can use a static ms count and multiple it by the current index of you li list to animate further out from *right now*.

I believe you are actually looking for something like this, which loops over your li list, and sets a transform to occur on each item 100ms from the previous:

```
function changeLi() {
  [].forEach.call(li, function(li, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      li.style.transform = "translateX(200px)";
    }, 100 * i);
  });
}
```

Comment: That is somewhat working, but it stops after 2 iterations.
It animates the first Item properly, then follows up animating the whole UL at once.
Is there a way to use bind() for the "this" context?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are right, I indeed try to get the transforms to occur in sequence after a given timeframe.

Comment: Perfect, just seen your edit, this works flawlessly now:-)