# animate() stops working when clicking too fast on the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with an animation.

```
var i = 0;
$('.next').on('click', function() {         
  if (i < 4) {      
        $('li').animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 300);  
        i++;
  }
  console.log($('li:first').position().left);
  console.log(i);
});

$('.back').on('click', function() {
    if ($('li:first').position().left < 0) {    
        $('li').animate({'left': '+=600px'}, 300);
        i--;
  }
  console.log(i);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6t1wx95f/10/

When you click 4 times on the button 'Next', you will see all the images and everything works fine. But if you click on it many times and very fast, it will stop working and you won't see the last image.

So there are 2 options for me:

1. The animation should go on (in this case very fast), no matter how fast the button has
   been clicked.
2. Wait 300ms until the animation is finished and then go on with `i++`
   or `i--;`.

What's the easiest way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of your condition check:

```js
if (i < 4) {   
  $('li').animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 300);  
  i++;
}
```

You are increment variable **i** for each click on the button, you should somehow disable the button until the animation is over to avoid this.

@edit
This answer may help you, he's talking about css animation events.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210785/8658255

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
var i = 0;

function next() {
  if (i < 4) {      
    $('li').animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 300);  
    i++;
  }
}

var throttledNext = _.throttle(next, 1200, { leading: true, trailing: false });

$('.next').on('click', throttledNext);
```

It requires the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) and it's [_.throttle()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) method. The essence of throttling is just:

> By using _.throttle, we don't allow to our function to execute more
>   than once every X milliseconds.

So all of your intermediate clicks (between the animation phases) will be thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my own question and the solution is easy, since what I need is `delay()`.

So instead of `$('li').animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 300)`, I just use `$('li').animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 300).delay(600);`

https://jsfiddle.net/6t1wx95f/11/