# detect if element is being transitioned

Tags: css, css-transitions

How to detect via js if any sort of transition is being applied to the element right now?

#### Short story of my problem:

I have a situation where I'm firing a function on the `transitionend` event, but sometimes the element doesn't have any *transition* being applied (because in Firefox, for example, the user might click some element rapidly which makes the transition goes crazy and stop working) so I want to know when it doesn't work and just fire the function myself, skipping the `transitionend`. I am trying to avoid ugly solutions..

Comment: When your problem includes any specific browser, and the words "goes crazy and stops working" I don't know that there is a pretty solution...

Comment: the specifics of the problem is not really an issue, and it's on all browsers.. i just gave a very specific example for the curios folks, but my question stands and it's something I would like to know even if I hadn't faced a problem.

Comment: I know, I was just giving you a hard time. I would actually like to know as well. I've run into problems with css-transitions before, as is evidenced by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288977/element-style-display-none-not-working-in-firefox-but-is-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Web Animation API for that, notably the [`Element#getAnimations`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) method, which will return a list of [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) objects applied on the Element. These will include Web Animations (from [`.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)), CSS `@keyframes` animations, and [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSTransition).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((el) => {
  el.onmouseenter = (evt) => {
    const animations = el.getAnimations(); // we could also ask to look in the subtree
    // we're only interested in CSS transitions
    const transitions = animations.filter((anim) => anim instanceof CSSTransition);
    console.log(transitions.length
      ? transitions.map((anim) => anim.transitionProperty )
      : "no transition"
    );
  };
});
```

```css
a:hover {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.color-transition {
  transition: color 1s;
}
.color-and-opacity-transition {
  transition: color 1s, opacity 5s;
}

/*SO-only*/.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 110px !important }
```

```html
<b>Hover these anchors to log their applied transitions.</b><br>
<a class="color-transition">color transition</a><br>
<a class="color-and-opacity-transition">color &amp; opacity transition</a><br>
<a>no transition</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `transitionstart`, `transitionend`, and, `transitioncancel` events. To tell if some element is under transition. However, you cannot know if some element *will* start a transition (even if it has `transition-delay: 0s`) using this code:

```js
/** @type {Map<HTMLElement, number>} */
const transitionCounter = new Map();
/** @type {(() => void)[]} */
const waitingTransition = [];

const incReference = (counter, target) => {
  if (counter.has(target)) {
    counter.set(target, counter.get(target) + 1);
  } else {
    counter.set(target, 1);
  }
};
const desReference = (counter, target) => {
  if (!counter.has(target)) {
    return;
  } else if (counter.get(target) === 1) {
    counter.delete(target);
  } else {
    counter.set(target, counter.get(target) - 1);
  }
};
document.addEventListener('transitionstart', event => {
  const { target } = event;
  incReference(transitionCounter, target);
  const onFinish = event => {
    if (event.target !== target) return;
    desReference(transitionCounter, target);
    target.removeEventListener('transitioncancel', onFinish);
    target.removeEventListener('transitionend', onFinish);
    [...waitingTransition].forEach(listener => { listener(); });
  };
  target.addEventListener('transitioncancel', onFinish);
  target.addEventListener('transitionend', onFinish);
});

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const isUnderTransition = function (element) {
  const parents = [];
  for (let i = element; i; i = i.offsetParent) parents.push(i);
  return Array.from(transitionCounter.keys()).some(running => parents.includes(running));
};

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
const waitTransitionEnd = async function (element) {
  if (!isUnderTransition(element)) return Promise.resolve();
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    waitingTransition.push(function listener() {
      if (isUnderTransition(element)) return;
      waitingTransition.splice(waitingTransition.indexOf(listener), 1);
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

As specified by [W3C Editor's Draft - CSS Transition](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/#transition-events)

> The ‘transitionend’ event occurs at the completion of the transition. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed, then the event will not fire.

So, I think there's not a valid *simple way* to solve this problem. The solution is left to the implementation (the browser) which decide if it does or doesn't render the transition at all.

Maybe, a solution could be to attach a listener to the element that fires the transition and after a specific elapsed time it checks if the *transitioned* element has the required CSS attributes set, and if those attributes aren't set as expected you can run your function by yourself.

Comment: yes I've thought about using some setTimeout method but..it's just ugly. i'm very surprised there is no "ongoingTransition" flag in the W3C draft or something of the sort.

Comment: yes, it's a big limit, I hope when they will reach the final specifications, more events will be available. But currently, I guess the only way is to rely on custom timed functions which simulate the missing event callbacks.

Comment: that means synchronizing the timing of the CSS and the JS manually..tedious.