# CSS trigger javascript after transition/animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm not looking to trigger a CSS animation from JS, but rather the opposite.

If I do a CSS animation via the `-webkit-transition` or `transition: all 1000ms` type style sheet, is there a way to trigger a JS function after the transition is done?

Basically I've been doing animations via javascript and I want to convert some of them to CSS animations, but I need to trigger javascript events after the animations have completed.

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition

Comment: Awesome I didn't find that before posting. I need to fully test it but it seems to fit my needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback on CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
box.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { 
     alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
}, false );
```

See: [Callback on CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition)

Comment: Thanks. I missed the original post.