# Apply CSS properties when transition ends

Tags: css, css-transitions

How do I have the properties of a declaration apply to an element *after* the CSS3 transitions end? I have something like:

```
.something {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  transition: box-shadow 300ms;
}
.something:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

I'd like the padding and margin properties in the :hover declaration to be applied after the transition is done in 300ms.

Comment: Have a look at this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087510/1577396).

Answer (score 32):

you can add a delay like this:

```
transition: box-shadow 300ms, padding 300ms 400ms;
```

The `box-shadow` transition will start on hover and last 300ms, and the `padding` will start after 400ms and again last 300ms.

```css
.something {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  background-clip: context-box;
  transition: box-shadow 300ms, padding 300ms 400ms;
}

.something:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px blue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='something'>Something</div>
```

[Article on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/transition-delay-delays/)

Comment: This is genius and works for non-transitionable properties like `overflow` (it doesn't transition, it's just applied after the duration).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by placing another element inside or outside `.something` and applying padding and margin transitions to the new element, but with `transition-delay` value set to the time equal or greater than time of your initial `box-shadow` transition.

So, for instance:

```
<div class="immediate">
    <div class="later">
        I can haz transitions.
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.immediate {
  background: #eeb;
  transition: box-shadow 300ms;
}

.immediate:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}

.later {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px 0;
   transition: all 400ms;
   transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.later:hover {
   margin: 10px 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

This will perform the `box-shadow` transition in 300ms, and afterwards `margin` and `padding` in 400ms (you can set this transition time to 0 if that's the effect you're looking for).

You can try it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gTVVk/2/

**EDIT:** [Duncan Beattie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16731051/688865) will do just fine, unless you need to perform different transitions on the same property. Otherwise there's no point to overcomplicate things with nested divs.

Answer (score 3):

When using @Duncan Beattie´s solution one property will override the other.
This should work:

```
transition: box-shadow 300ms linear, padding 300ms linear 400ms;
```

Syntax:

```
transition: [property] [duration] [timing-function] [delay], ... more property-transitions
```