# Animate.css - Wait for animation to finish before continuing

Tags: jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I'm currently using Animate.css for animation around the app I'm creating. I'm looking for a way to wait for the animation to finish before continuing. Here's what I thought would of worked, but doesn't. Any help is appcieated!

```
$("#myDiv").addClass("animated flipOutY", function() {
  return $("#myDiv").empty();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cross-browser way to do this except for setting a timeout.

```
setTimeout($('#myDiv').empty, 500);
```

There are some browser-prefixed methods for this, but I think I remember them being unreliable. See this SO question: [Callback on CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition)

Answer (score 5):

If this is about CSS animations then this

```
$("#myDiv").addClass("animated flipOutY")
           .on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e) {
              $(this). ...
           });
```

If that animate.css uses actually transitions then you should use these events:

```
'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd'
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem :)
`$(".loader_calendar").addClass('animated zoomOut').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(e) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });`