# Race condition with CSS transitions and transitionend event - Cannot find a solution

Tags: javascript, css, events, asynchronous, transition

I think most of you know that you cannot trigger a transition just after appending an element to the DOM without asking for computed styles. OK, I get it, and this problem is related somehow.

I just need to rely on the JS 'transitionend' event to remove an element from the DOM after the transition ends (fade-out effect).
The problem is that adding a CSS class and removing it (without timers) doesn't trigger the transition and so the event is never fired, letting the element stay in the DOM forever.

I even tried using setTimeout(f, 0) and requestAnimationFrame(f) to remove the class after the addition and let the transition start, but no luck at all.
I even combined calls to getComputedStyle to trigger repaint, before and after adding/removing the class. Still no luck.

Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/demian85/oprn9jzk/1/

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) { // this never gets called
    console.log(e);
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
});

button.classList.add('hover');
button.clientWidth;
button.classList.remove('hover');
```

The only ugly solution I found is to use setTimeout with at least 50ms of delay. But we are using a test framework that should wait 50ms before interacting with the DOM, and that's not a viable solution at all.

Does anyone knows how can I handle this situation? Why isn't there any transitionstart event?

pd: tested in Chrome 39

Thanks.

Comment: A valid example would be a component with methods fadeIn() and fadeOut(). If those methods are called sequentially, the event listener would never be called.

Comment: Does this need to actually display the transition, or simply remove the element when the class is removed?

Comment: Of course I want the transition to occur.
But what I still don't understand is what happens if the user somehow manages to trigger those calls in less than 50ms... Does the event execute or not?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand your requirements now: You are using a hover class in your example code, but I presume in reality you want to use a :hover pseudo-class to trigger the fade transition. But you're worried that if the user mouses away very quickly (< 50ms) the transitionend event won't be sent.

The answer is not to use :hover. Instead, add a mouseover listener and manually add a class that causes the fade transition, and don't remove it. That way, the fade transition is guaranteed to run to completion, and the transitionend event will definitely be fired.

E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/vw3t627g/1/

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   button.classList.add('bye-bye'); 
});

button.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
});
```