# How can I fire a function after an HTML animation ended?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

This is my CSS:

```
.animated {
 transition: 1s;
 left: -400px;
 }
```

I want to element after it class name has been set to .animated. and after it finish the transition I want to fire a function. Can someone please suggest me the idea?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition

Comment: Use the animation callback `$("#myDiv").animate({width:'100px'}, 200, function() { console.log("After animation"); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transitionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event, it's fired when a CSS transition has completed:

```
function showMessage() {
    alert('Transition has finished');
}

var element = document.getElementById("animated");
element.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false);
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPdqMB)