# Animate.CSS - Remove class after end of animation with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to make a button so whenever I click it the animation plays. But the problem that I have is when I click the button, the animation doesn't play because the class is already applied. I want to know how to remove the class when the animation is done. I know this can be done with jQuery, but I want to know how to do it with just regular vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback on CSS transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition)

Comment: I'm assuming here you're talking about a CSS-based animation, since it's not terribly clear in your question.

Comment: I've added some ways on removing classes and the link for more info, I dont think i've really answered your question however, what do you want to do with CSS? Can you add a small example via JFiddle so we can see what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is

```
ELEMENT.classList.remove("CLASS_NAME");
```

Versus

```
document.getElementById("whatever").className = "";
```

Which removes **all** classes, not **a** class

Or perhaps this

```
div.classList.add("foo");
div.classList.remove("foo");
```

See more from [Remove Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155737/remove-css-class-from-element-with-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("yourBTNClass")[0]; // Your (N-1)th button
btn.onclick = function() {
   btn.className = "yourBTNClass"; // Setting the class back to what it was before
   animation(); // The function your animation takes place in
   btn.className = ""; // Reseting the class
}
```

Hope you found this useful! :)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you want to know how to modify the class of a particular element with javascript (not jQuery).

This is how I would do it:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").className = "";
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT 1**

So it sounds like you want the class to be removed automatically once the event has finished, rather than some external action removing the class.

I think the best way to go would be to create your own eventListener function for animation like jQuery has. Here is a good example that I found:

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

/* Listen for a transition! */
var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
transitionEvent && e.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
    console.log('Transition complete!  This is the callback, no library needed!');
});
```

Source: https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback

Comment: That doesn't work, I want the animation to end before it removes the class.