# Use standard JS promises with jQuery addClass call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to get a series of events to occur in the browser one after the other, but JavaScript being asynchronous makes that difficult.  I'm using jQuery to handle adding and removing classes, and I want to use standard JS promises to make everything occur in sequence but I'm having a hard time of things.  What I'm trying to do is wrap the jQuery event in Promise.resolve() and use that to call .then() (I've had success with this in the past with AJAX calls.)  For example:

```js
    makePromise = function() {
      return Promise.resolve($(".mydiv").addClass("grow").promise());
     }
    makePromise().then(function() {
      alert("running");
    })
```

```css
    .mydiv {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .mydiv.grow {
     transition: width 2s;
        width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
    </div>
```

[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cugamer/5yjtjoe8/1)

The intent is for the jQuery event to run it's course, then run what's going on in the then() call, but as you can see it's marching right on into the next step without waiting.  Is there a way to make this play work or am I going in the wrong direction entirely?  Help me Stack Overflow Hivemind, you're my only hope.

Comment: `addClass` is synchronous, why are you trying to wrap it in a promise?

Comment: Just remove the `Promise.resolve`, leave it like this: `return $(".mydiv").addClass("grow").promise();`. If you want the animation to end before showing the alert you probably want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087510/callback-on-css-transition).

Comment: If you want to wait for the CSS transition, you will need to explicitly wait for that event. `addClass` is simple synchronous DOM modification.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is [synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035662/4355342) by default. So you can make whatever your window events one after other, if they are not `async` calls like

`setTimeout`

`AJAX`

`Promise` (not directly)

So your events can be sequenced without using `Promise`.

```js
$(".mydiv").addClass("grow");

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("running");
  }, 2000);
```

```css
.mydiv {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: width 2s;
    }

    .mydiv.grow {
      width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
    </div>
```

And even `Promise` is used to make `JavaScript` asynchronous.

As an example

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  console.log("First"); //Executes first.
  resolve();
});

promise.then(function(){ //purely async, called and not waited for response
  console.log("Third"); //after execution of promise.
});

console.log("second"); //not waited for promise.then
```

Then coming to your expectation of making sequential execution using `Promise`. We need some `asynchronism` to ask `resolve` to wait for sometime, so used basic `setTimeout` to achieve this.

```js
makePromise = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         $(".mydiv").addClass("grow").promise()
         setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
      })
     }
    makePromise().then(function() {
      alert("running");
    })
```

```css
.mydiv {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: width 3s;
    }

    .mydiv.grow {
      width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
    </div>
```

**Note:** I think some issue with your `transition` for `width`. correct it for better result.

Hope this helps.