# How can I write a function that undoes the action after a few seconds?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

How can I write a function that undoes the action after a few seconds?
I am adding a class to an element with the purpose to create a short animation. I know I can set the animation time with css, but how do I remove the class after a few seconds?
Should I create another animation setTimeout()?

Here is my code:

```
const copyAnimation = (item) => {
    item.classList.add('copied');
};
copyTextArea.addEventListener('click', () => {
  copyAnimation(clonedCode);
});
```

Comment: yup, sounds good.

Comment: If you want to remove the class when the CSS animation ends, there is a solution for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087669/1552587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
const copyAnimation = (item) => {
    item.classList.add('copied');
    setTimeout(function(){  item.classList.remove('copied'); }, 3000);
};
copyTextArea.addEventListener('click', () => {
  copyAnimation(clonedCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can go with this =>

```
 setTimeout(
         function() 
        {
          $(this).removeClass("loader-input");
         }, 3000
);
```